# Xamarin.forms offline google map

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin.forms, google-maps-api-3

I'm new in Xamarin.forms ...
I used Google map API to my app , and did some function... load map, pin, geocoder...etc..
Now , I want to use offline google map in my app...
I download some KML files already...
Is it possible to use  KML file ?
But now i didnt find how to load KML file and KMLlayer in my app..
Find some utili like this : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/setup
But dont know hot to use ,,, binding ?? or what...
My English is not well too ,,  thanks for ur answers ..

Comment: Unfortunately,If you use Xamarin forms, it do not have this feature. If you use custom renderer to achieve it, I find OpenStreetMap it could be achieve it.You can see this thread.http://blog.cayas.de/extend-your-xamarin-android-app-with-openstreetmap

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT  I find the Xamarin.Android.Maps.Utils AAR file , and unzip to JAR file. and then binding it to my project ,, now it can call that classes to use~
But now the project get something wrong...i try to solve it ...

Comment: Do you use this nuget package?https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Maps.Utils , If so, just install it in your  NuGet package Manager, and then you can use it directly.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT sure, but cant do anything ,, about KML files......or i dont know how to use this package...?

Comment: If use install the nuget packages, could you use `KmlLayer` in your project? If so, this link have a demo https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils you can download it and learn it.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT cannot use~~ so i dont know how T_T....